# HP ML350 G6 will not power on

Tags: hp, electrical-power, troubleshooting, diagnostic

I have no lights on MB or back of power supply.  I have replaced power supply and added a redundant power supply. I replaced PD board or backplane whatever you want to call it.  Still same result.  Replaced motherboard same issue.  Have tried the plug power supply in before inserting into server no luck.  I am totally lost at this point.  What can I try next?

Comment: you can power some think else with the cable of this server or also other device is not powered using the same electric cable?

Comment: Have tried several outlets and 3 different power cables

Comment: You can proceed by connecting things on motherboard one by one; but as you says if power supply does not powered also if have no connection with the server seems to be there the problem, they have any fuse to be checked?

Comment: I have a very similar state of a server. Were you able to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that at least standby power LED gets on.

   2. Disconnect everything from the motherboard and try again with a single PSU and CPU, no RAM, RAID controller etc.
   3. Find the CMOS reset button and clear BIOS.
   4. Look for leaking electrolytic capacitors 
      [image]
      and physical damage to the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and found the way to start server. There is signal contacts on the PS if you short two of them Power Supply will start(like on ordinary PC power sypply). You need to short contact 1 and 4(look foto below). I used this method just to test if PS work itself out of the server. After that i've tried to short this contacts on the PS backplate. And gess what? Yep, server powered on.It works Ok, you can ON and OFF server many times. Until I unplug the power cord. If I do so I need to short contacts again. If I short it fast, server led just turn on and it ready to be powered on by power botton, if I short it for 1-2 sec it starts working.
I didn't find what cause this, but i gess it's capasitor problem that a didn't see.
Finaly I've soldered button to this contacts, so I can start server without disassembling it. Also you need to solder the button on the same port you plug PS, or 2 buttons for 2 PS's configuration :-)
Sorry for my English :-) [foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvCvY.jpg)